# How to get data from firebase cloud firestore in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am able to post data in firebase cloud firestore, but I am facing problem in getting data from that.

Below are my code

firebase.js

```
import firebase from "firebase";

var firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    authDomain: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    databaseURL: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    projectId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    storageBucket: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    appId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
})
var db = firebaseApp.firestore();
export { db };
```

Below code is to get data from firebase cloud firestore:

FormStatus.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { db } from "../firebase";

class FormStatus extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { form: [], }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        db.database().ref("form").on("value", snapshot => {
            let form = [];
            snapshot.forEach(snap => {
                form.push(snap.val());
            })
            this.setState({ form: form })
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.form.map(data => {
                    return (
                        <ul>
                            <li>{data.name}</li>
                            <li>{data.location}</li>
                        </ul>
                    )
                })}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default FormStatus;
```

I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: _firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.db.database is not a function
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is effectively trying to execute this:

```
firebase.firestore().database()
```

That's not valid.  If you want the Firebase Database reference, you should simple execute:

```
firebase.database()
```

This means you probably don't want to export `firebase.firestore()` from your firebase.js file.  Firestore is a different database with a different API.

You could export this:

```
export { firebaseApp };
```

Then import later like this:

```
import { firebaseApp } from "./firebase"

firebaseApp.database().ref(...)
```

Comment: I am getting a blank page. There is no content on the page

Answer (score 0):

Change  db.database().ref("form") to db.collection("form")